# How to Install our android image in laptop ? How to make android boot-able image for laptop?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, fastboot, bootloader

I have Android Source Code image and i want to install it on Laptop . I want to know how we made bootable image for laptop with android image. 
What I have to do so that laptop detect the android image. 
There is some site which provide android image for laptop , in which i have to download image but i want my android image been install in laptop. Is any tool is present which make boot loader for android image.GUIDE ME

Comment: Unless you have an ARM-based desktop, you need an emulator. There is one included in the Android SDK (for Windows, Linux, etc.).  **Can you re-state your question?**

Comment: i have x86 system and android 4.0 image.Can it's possible to make such a bootable image like here  http://www.android-x86.org/download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check out [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) project. They have documentation and [installation instruction](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/installhowto) for installing an Android on a regular laptop/desktop.

Comment: thanks Ryan . Can it's possible to make iso image for booting from your android image ? .Just like Android x86.

Comment: @i_max 77: [build instruction for android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode), there is also build instruction for making isos. You can't use your own image, at least not without rebasing the patches that android x86 are maintaining into your image and recompiling everything.

Comment: This would require any applications to be recompiled (or be available in source).  Looks interesting ..